# Recorrer json array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

Tengo el siguiente json:

```
[{titulo : "Total", balesia : 1, torre:2, CT:3, HF :6}, {titulo : "Total", balesia : 4, torre:2, CT:5, HF :8} ]
```

Necesito recorrerlo y sumar solo los que tienen valor numérico y almacenarlo en otro objeto.

¿Cómo recorrer este objeto json y sumar los valores numéricos para almacenar el resultado de la suma en otro objeto?

No soy tan bueno en javascript.

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: Si ya lo hice, tuve q deshacer ese formato y crear otro

Answer (score 4):

Respuesta si **no sabes el tipo** de dato que tenes dentro del objecto:

```js
    let res = 0;
    let a = [
         {titulo : "Total", balesia : 1, torre:2, CT:3, HF :6}, 
         {titulo : "Total", balesia : 4, torre:2, CT:5, HF :8}
    ];

    /**
     * Ésto lo resuelve
     */
    a.forEach((e)=>{
                     for(var p in e){
                       typeof e[p] == "number" && (res+=e[p]);
                     }
                   }
    );

    console.log("Resultado: " + res);
```

Con esto sólo sumas los que sean números, no importa que variables tenga el objeto. Espero que te sirva! Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

```
var tuJSON = [{titulo : "Total", balesia : 1, torre:2, CT:3, HF :6}, {titulo : "Total", balesia : 4, torre:2, CT:5, HF :8} ];
var retorno = 0;
tuJSON.forEach(function(currentValue,index,arr) {
    retorno += currentValue.balesia + currentValue.torre + currentValue.CT + currentValue.HF;
});
console.log(retorno);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar Array.reduce() para obtener el objeto

```js
var arr = [
  {
    titulo : "Total", 
    balesia : 1, 
    torre:2, 
    CT:3, 
    HF :6
  }, 
  {
    titulo : "Total", 
    balesia : 4, 
    torre:2, 
    CT:5, 
    HF :8
  } 
]


var res = arr.reduce(function(anterior,actual){
  return {
    balesia: anterior.balesia   + actual.balesia,
    torre: anterior.torre   + actual.torre,
    CT: anterior.CT   + actual.CT,
    HF: anterior.HF   + actual.HF
  }
},{
  balesia:0,
  torre:0,
  CT:0,
  HF:0
})
console.log(res);
```

*Reduce* toma dos parámetros:

1. Funcion que toma el  valor anterior y el valor actual del arreglo
2. Valor inicial ( es pasado a la funcion como valor anterior para el primer elemento)

y regresa el objeto directamente;

Al iniciar *Reduce* con un objeto con las propiedades que queremos podemos sumar cada propiedad del arreglo y obtener un nuevo objeto con sus propiedades iguales a la suma de las propiedades de cada elemento del arreglo

Para obtener más información acerca de [*Reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)